# Python funny array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I came across this code in Python:

```
processed = data[:,feature_locs]
```

I tried testing this sort of code out with this

```
    ha = (3, 5, 7)
    print ha
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    print data[:, ha]
```

but I get a `TypeError`.

What am I doing wrong, and what does the above syntax mean?

Comment: Where did you spot the first snippet?

Comment: Looks like a 2-dimensional index as used by `numpy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a custom `slice` argument supported by the `numpy` module for multidimensional arrays.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.random((2,3))
>>> a
array([[ 0.01211291,  0.06738324,  0.11690497],
       [ 0.86175703,  0.21903569,  0.49506358]])
>>> a[:,1]
array([ 0.06738324,  0.21903569])
```

See the numpy documentation for more details http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 4):

when you are working with a 2 dimensional array (or list of lists) using this syntax addresses the whole first dimension and the range specified in the second argument. as such -

```
s = [11, 12, 13, 14]
s2 = [21, 22, 23, 24]
s3 = [s, s2] # List of lists
s4 = array(s3) # 2-dimensional array

print s4[:,1:3]
-> [[12, 13],
    [22, 23]]
```

as you can see, this runs over the first dimension entirely and prints the second and third element of the second dimensions

**EDIT:**
as mentioned by @tobias_k in the comments - the array() function is provided by the numpy package so you need to add a proper import for it.
this syntax is provided by the package for 2-dimensional arrays and not for ordinary list-of-lists.

Comment: You should add that `array` is a function from the `numpy` package. It does not work with "ordinary" lists of lists.